# ASP.NET: cache task and call its result in synchronous code

Tags: asp.net, caching, async-await, task

I have synchronous **HttpHandler**. I want to cache result of **HttpClient.GetAsync** and use it in my **HttpHandler**. I did it this way:

```
public static class CacheFacade
{
    private static Cache Cache => HttpRuntime.Cache;
    private const string CacheKey = "asynccache";
    private static readonly object _lockObject = new object();

    public static string GetStringFromCache()
    {
        if (Cache[CacheKey] == null)
        {    
            lock(_lockObject)
            {   
                if (Cache[CacheKey] == null)
                {
                    InitCache();
                }
            }

            //fallback here; I can use data from some synchronous source
            return "init cache" + " - " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        }
        var task = (Task<string>) Cache[CacheKey];

        if (!task.IsCompleted)
        {
            //and fallback here too
            return task.Status + " - " + DateTime.UtcNow + " - " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        }

        return task.Result;
    }

    private static void InitCache()
    {
        var task = Task.Run(GetDataAsync);
        Cache.Insert(CacheKey, task, null, DateTime.Now.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)),
            Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
    }

    private static async Task<string> GetDataAsync()
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
            var res = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://www.google.com");
            return res.StatusCode + " - " + DateTime.UtcNow + " - " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        }
    }
}
```

It works. Does this approach have any disadvantages?
**UPDATE**: added lock with double check according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking .

Comment: Any concrete concerns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is OK.

Note, that these cache items can only be stored in-process. You can't use an out-of-process cache because tasks cannot be serialized. You might or might not care about that.

In your `fallback here; I can use data from some synchronous source` handling you can also block on the task (or await it if architecturally possible).

HTTP handlers support async processing using tasks as well. I believe you need a tiny helper/wrapper for that which is easy to write or available on the web.

Comment: Yes, I know it requires in-process mode.

Comment: About fallback: in actual project I have synchronous call to database there.

Comment: I know I can use async httphandlers but project is quite big and in many places it's quite difficult to introduce asynchronous workflow.

Comment: I'm thinking about access to this static class from multiple requests. HttpRuntime.Cache is threadsafe so check for null and other work ok (I suppose). BUT: if I want to cache data in static variable instead of cache it's requred to add lock for "if (Cache[CacheKey] == null) {...}", right?

Comment: You're only using the thread safe cache here so there are no concerns. With a static var you'd indeed need to synchronize. A `ConcurrentDict<TKey, Lazy<TValue>>` is an easy and safe solution but it does not support eviction.

Comment: it's possible situation when two threads can find empty cache and execute InitiCache method in parallel. Isn't it? So my thought is to add lock inside "Cache[CacheKey] == null".

Comment: That's possible. The best way to avoid that is to add a `Lazy<Task<...>>` to the cache. That ensures that the task is only created once. The ConcurrentDict solution also has this behavior.